# Ruby - end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: /

Tags: ruby, eval

I'm getting different error based on space between after divide(/) operator. Lets consider following example.

```
$ ruby -e "a /100"
-e:1: unterminated string meets end of file
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_END, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tREGEXP_END or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR


$ ruby -e "a / 100"
-e:1: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

The second example gives proper error message while the first one gives weird error. I did some research, but couldn't find out the reasons behind it. Is there anyway to fix this to give proper error messge?

Comment: I think the actual message you get in the first example, depends on the Ruby version. Are you using a pre-2.0 Ruby? With Ruby 2.2, I get the message which @Shimu is saying. I don't have access to an older Ruby right now, but I tried it with a JRuby version which is based on Ruby 1.9, and with this I get at least your *unterminated string ....* message.

Answer (score 1):

If I try this with Ruby 2.3.1, I get this message: `-e:1: unterminated regexp meets end of file` Which seems valid since "/" is normally a regex marker...
And in the second line of your error message it says it is expecting a tREGEXP_END.
So, I think, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in the terminal and got the same regexp error:

```
$ ruby -e "a /100"
-e:1: unterminated regexp meets end of file
```

It seems like the `/100` was interpreted as a regexp. The simple solution is to follow the correct ruby syntax (i.e. your second example: `$ ruby -e "a / 100"` ). Normally, it is recommended to add spaces around ruby operators, as suggest by the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).